# How to batch two select queries in sqlalchemy to avoid multiple requests?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to batch independent database requests in SQLAlchemy? Say I have a setup like this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    desc = Column(String)

def get_all_users_and_items(session: Session):
    users = session.query(User).all()
    items = session.query(Item).all()
    return users, items
```

As I understand it, each `.all()` in the `get_all_users_and_items` function will result in a separate request to the database. Perhaps there is some laziness that the requests are not issued until the items are iterated over, but iterating over users and then items will result in two separate requests, i.e. two round trips to the database. If I know ahead of time that I will be iterating over both users and items, it seems wasteful to have two round trips to the database, and I'm hoping there is a way to have a single round-trip where I tell the database "hey, I need all the users and all the items, but separately".

Is this possible in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Are you actually seeing a performance problem? Also, which database are you interacting with over HTTP?

Comment: @ndc85430 My mistake, just "requests" not HTTP requests.

Comment: No, there is no way to avoid two calls. You don't have _anything_ (like a `ForeignKey`) linking the tables so I'm not sure how you expect the API to respond to such a request

Comment: @roganjosh I was hoping that instead of ["Me: Hey DB, give me the Users", "DB: Here are the Users: A, B, C", "Me: Hey DB, give me the Items", "DB: Here are the Items: X, Y, Z"] it could go ["Me: Hey DB, give me the Users, then give me the Items", "DB: Here are the Users: A, B, C. Here are the Items: X, Y, Z"]. Wanting to minimize round-trips seems like a very natural thing to want even when requests are unrelated given that waiting on the network is orders of magnitude slower than anything else in sight.

Comment: You overstate the overhead of the double request. If the two tables were related in some way, there might be a sensible way to combine the response. As it is - there just isn't

Comment: You could maybe do some weird stuff with CTEs in a raw query but I really don't even want to try putting that framework together because it's awful

Comment: "given that waiting on the network is orders of magnitude slower than anything else in sight" - Yes, but if it takes 10 seconds to *receive* the users over the network and another 10 seconds to *receive* the items, and sending each of the two requests takes 500 ms then you would add a lot of complexity to save just one 500 ms request (reducing 21 seconds of total network time to 20.5 seconds).